# tensorboard not showing steps beyond some point

Tags: tensorboard, tensorboardx

I am trying to visualize a log file from tensorboard, but it only shows it up to certain point. I am using tensorboard 2.7, and my system is ubuntu 18.
I have changed from Windows to Ubuntu, and in windows I was able to see all the steps.
I have 66k steps uptil now, but I can only see it 11,039. I used also this tag: `--max_reload_threads 4`, and `--samples_per_plugin images=99999999,` and `--samples_per_plugin scalars=999999999` but it didn't help. My logfile is nearly 4GB. I had no problem loading 13GB logfile in Windows with the same system.
I also disabled --load_fast=false, and now it shows 10,799 steps, and it display this error each few seconds: `E1102 13:43:21.874801 139799442822912 plugin_event_multiplexer.py:235] Unable to reload accumulator '.': [Errno 5] Input/output error`

I also increased the swap file to 64GB, but not then and not now, system is not using it, so I don't think that it's related to memory either.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many different things, but it was weirdly enough solved by restarting my workstation. Still, I don't know why this happened.